# Поддержка разных разрешений

Tags: android

1. Есть 2 разрешения 800х480 4" и 960х540 4.3". Все элементы отображаются корректно, кроме размера шрифта. Создал 2 dimens с разными размерами, но не могу понять как их раскидать по папкам: оба поддерживают hdpi и normal screen. Можно было бы прописать sw332  или h600 для 960х540, но тогда 800х480 4.3" и 4.5" попадают тоже сюда (для всех 800х480 - другой размер шрифта).
2. В eclipse AVD запускаю 5.1" и 6" 800х480 mdpi, large. В values есть 2 папки: mdpi и large-mdpi. Данные берутся почему-то из папки mdpi, хотя по идее должны браться из large-mdpi. Это глюк AVD или еще есть какие-то тонкости?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. для первого положите размер в дефолтную папку без модификаторов, для второго с модификатором `sw360`
2. Из документации:

> Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width.

Уже пора перестать пользоваться `normal/large/xlarge`, только если делаете что-то для API < 13. Очень надеюсь что нет.
Положите в `sw480dp` и все будет работать корректно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.